# Loading data error. Why isn't it loading?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am trying to set up google sheets to pull data from an API. At first it worked, now it just says "Loading error..." on the cell with the formula.

I have tried it on a new sheet. I have simplified it to one input variable.

```
function getPrice(item,city){
  var url = "https://www.albion-online-data.com/api/v1/stats/prices/"+item+"? 
  locations="+city;
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var object = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());
  return object[0].sell_price_min;
}
```

The variables are "item" and "city". For which examples include "T1_Wood" item in "Caerleon" city. I'd like to make a table to pull the prices for different items in different cities. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried your code as written and it worked fine.  It returned "14".  Are you still asking why it isn't loading, or do you want help with making the table?

Comment: I have the table done, I just have no idea why it isn't loading on my google sheet. It just shows "Loading..." with a red triangle at the top right of the cell. It is comforting to know that the code works though.

Comment: Does it work in the Script Editor?  Try making a test function and checking the output with View > Logs: `function test() { Logger.log(getPrice("T1_Wood", "Caerleon")); }`

Comment: When I tried running test() it said: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch. (line 3, file "Code") Thank you, you helped me figure out it was because I hit the quota google sheets put in place. I guess next step is to contact Google or to use a different gmail account to run the excel.

Comment: For reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas